# Array/Results Code not working

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon! I have 5 job titles in an array (mechanic, cleaner, driver, cashier, electrician). I'm also looking to have an input box and a submit button. I want to be able to put a number (let's say 3) and have the JS print out jobs 1,2 and 3, in this case it would print out mechanic, cleaner and driver. I'm a little confused on what to do. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: where is the code that you have tried

Comment: Use a for loop and access value inside array using index.

Comment: read this to enhance your question for better understanding.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

HOPE THIS HELPS...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnval').click(function(){
    $val=$('#txtval').val();
     //$val=3;
      var job = ['mechanic', 'cleaner', 'driver', 'cashier', 'electrician'];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < $val; i++) {
    text += job[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtval" />
<input type="button" value="Display" id="btnval" />
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript for your program would be as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Find the profession</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="txt">Output will appear here.</p>
    Enter your number:<input type="number" id="number">
    <button type="submit" id="button1" onclick="load()">Submit</button>
<script>
function load()
    {
var prof = ["mechanic", "cleaner", "driver", "cashier", "electrician"];
        var number=document.getElementById("number");
        var text="The answer is: ";
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=number.value;
        if(number.value<=5)
            {
                for(i=0;i<=number.value-1;i++)
                    {
                        text=text+prof[i]+" ";

                    }
                document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=text;
            }
    }
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script>
   var jobTitles = ['mechanic', 'cleaner', 'driver', 'cashier', 'electrician']
   function updatedisplay(){
   var displayStr="";
   for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById("countval").value;i++)
   {
  displayStr+=jobTitles[i]+" ";
   }
 document.getElementById("selectedDisplay").innerHTML = displayStr;
   }
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<label for="countval">Input values to display</label>
<input type="number" name="countval" id="countval" min="1" max="5"/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="updatedisplay()" />
<div id="selectedDisplay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```